# How can I initiate a JSF Flow and pass it parameters?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, flow-scope

I'm new to the world of Java programming (but not programming) and I have jumped in with two feet all the way up to my neck in trying to solve a problem.

I have a JSF 2.2 page which is currently creating a link such as this:

[My Link](/folder1/destination.jsf?id=xxxxx&param2=yyyyy&param3=zzzzz)

**/folder1/destination.jsf** was performing some work and then jumping to **/anotherfolder/destination2.jsf** and losing the bean in the jump.  I want to pass the bean over to the second page and thought using a JSF 2.2 FlowScoped bean would solve the problem.

I created the following FlowBuilder:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.faces.flow.Flow;
import javax.faces.flow.builder.*;

public class MyPageJumpingFlow extends Object implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Produces
    @FlowDefinition
    public Flow defineFlow(@FlowBuilderParameter FlowBuilder flowBuilder) {

        String flowId = "MyPageJumpingFlow";
        flowBuilder.id("", flowId);
        flowBuilder.viewNode(flowId, "/folder1/destination.xhtml").markAsStartNode();
        flowBuilder.viewNode(flowId+"2", "/anotherfolder/desintation2.xhtml");
        return(flowBuilder.getFlow());
    }
```

The backing bean for destination.jsf is instantiated this way:

```
@Named(value="destinationObject")
@FlowScoped("MyPageJumpingFlow")
```

My problem now is trying to understand how to start the flow and pass the parameters to it.

Any suggestions about how to do that or a better way to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Environment:  **JSF 2.2, Java EE 7, EclipseLink, Oracle Weblogic 12.1.3**